# Calculate indefinite integral not defined in zero

Tags: indefinite-integrals

I would like to know any clue to calculate this integral:
$\int_{R} \frac{1}{exp(x^{2})-a}$, where $a$ is a real parameter.

What methods could be used?

Answer (score 0):

If $R$ does not contain the point where $e^{x^2}=a$, one may use the series expansion
in terms of the error function:
$$\int \frac{1}{e^{x^2}-a}dx
=
\int \frac{e^{-x^2}}{1-ae^{-x^2}}dx
=
\sum_{k\ge 0} a^k \int e^{-(1+k)x^2}dx
=
\frac12 \sum_{k\ge 0} a^k \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{1+k}} Erf(\sqrt{1+k}x).
$$
Otherwise the integral is only defined as a principal value.